# AAPT: error: not well-formed (invalid token). asking for answers

Tags: java, encoding

So I'm trying to make an android app and tried to debug my xml.

I'm hoping on getting answers on how this code will function right.

Comment: As you are new here, Please add your code here that you are tried as well your question need to be more specific.

Comment: You want to read [ask] first.